# What's the right way to build a theme in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, best-practice

I hope this isn't a question too subjective a question for Stack Exchange. If so, feel free to correct me.

I've recently moved on from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1. Right now I'm trying to build my own theme. My current setup is as follows:

- All blocks are defined within a separate module, done analogously to `Magento_Theme`
- All layouts and parent overrides are defined within the theme

Could anybody tell me if this is the right way to go about it? If not, what would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Magento_Theme is not a theme (yes, it might be a little confusing ;) ). It's a module providing basic functionality for the theme('s).

For an example of how a theme should look like, magento provided the luma theme:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma

Answer (score 0):

### Create a storefront theme

The high-level steps required to add a new theme in the Magento system are the following:

1. Create a directory for the theme under `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>`
2. Add a declaration file **theme.xml** and optionally create an etc directory and create a file named **view.xml** to the theme directory.
3. Add a **composer.json** file.
4. Add registration.php.
5. Create directories for CSS, JavaScript, images, and fonts.
6. Configure your theme in the Admin panel.

You can see the content of the files and a complete step-by-step here:

[DevDocs: Create a new storefront theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)